# "Data Not Available" when accessing Visualforce Page with Flow Interview

Tags: visualforce, profile, visual-workflow

I have a flow that uses the `Parent_Opportunity_ID` variable to performance a Fast Lookup on the Opportunity object using the specific `Opportunity.Id`, then proceeds to show messages on a Screen based on the data. Here's the VF code:

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity">
    <apex:sectionHeader title="Create Opportunities" subtitle="Create  Opportunities"/>
    <flow:interview name="Create_Opportunities" finishLocation="/{!Opportunity.Id}">   
        <apex:param name="Parent_Opportunity_ID" value="{!Opportunity.Id}"/>
    </flow:interview>
</apex:page>
```

The solution works fine with the Admin profile, however whenever I use a non-admin profile, I get the error message:

```
Data Not Available
The data you were trying to access could not be found. It may be due to another user deleting the data or a system error. If you know the data is not deleted but cannot access it, please look at our support page.
```

I assume this is permissions related, but the profile I'm testing with has read/write to all of the fields I'm trying to access, has read/write/delete on the opportunity object, and is the Owner of the record that I'm access.

I turned on DEBUG logging for the user I'm testing with and there are no indications of any issues in the logs. There are no exception emails coming in.

I gave the profile View All permissions the Opportunity object, but still the problem persists.

I don't know how to debug this issue or where to go next. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it turns out, the problem was the user security profile did not have the `Run Flows` permission enabled. Once I enabled the this setting, the error went way.

Comment: I had the same problem. Assigning 'Run Flows' permission to the profile fixed the issue. Thanks Swisher Sweet!

Comment: Also note, if you don't want to give permission for Run Flows at the Profile level, the "Flow User" checkbox on the User record can be used to give permission to specific Users (it's like a precursor to actual Permission Sets). BOTH the User and Profile feature will give users the abillity to run ALL flows, unless you update the Flow itself to override this option as displayed in the Answer from User: cropredy below.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @SwisherSweet answer, the following will also generate this error:

- User **has** Run Flows permission (as Flow User, in Profile, or Permission Set)
- The Flow is configured so as to override default behavior as shown below
- The running user **has not been** granted permission to run the specific Flow (via Profile or Permission Set)

[image]